# RecyclerView peek behaviour

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagersnaphelper

I'm using a horizontal RecyclerView with PagerSnapHelper to make it look like a ViewPager. It's displaying child views.

How can I make it show a small peek of the next entry? The user needs to see close to 20% of the next entry to understand intuitively that they need to swipe horizontally. The earlier entry needs to align back.

There could be other indications of dots at the bottom but this is the expected behaviour. The child view occupies the entire recycler view, so adjusting the width of the child so as to make other siblings come onto the screen isn't an option.

Right now I'm using a RecyclerView that is set up with a PagerSnapHelper.

I'm able to scroll to 20% of the next entry by using this:

```
val nextPosition = (currentPosition + 1) % numOfEntries
val xscrollDistance = carouselRecyclerView.width * 0.80
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(nextPosition, xscrollDistance.toInt())
```

With this, I see the next entry come onto the screen like a peek but here's what I'm unhappy with:

1. This scroll isn't smooth, I'm looking for a smooth scroll to the 20% peek of the next entry
2. Snap doesn't work. I was hoping when I do step 1., the snap behaviour will kick in and align the earlier entry onto the screen. It doesn't happen that way.
3. The peeking behaviour also needs to be cyclic. Last entry's peek should be the 0th entry.

I'm also looking for a less complex solution if any.

I checked an older solution - [How to peek RecyclerView + PagerSnapHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884679/how-to-peek-recyclerview-pagersnaphelper) but I'm hoping to find a cleaner solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code on which I've been working that achieves the behaviour you describe. (**Disclaimer:** It seems not to work finely in nested recyclers, but it works fine out of the box for the case you were asking). Of course, it could be improved and you may need to twitch it a bit if you have any particular needs.

**Usage**

In essence, the peeking behaviour is about scrolling a bit and then scrolling back (or forward in your case) after a while. So here's how you use it:

```kotlin
val peekingDistance = 200
val timeBeforeNextPeeking = 1000L
// You don't have to attach it to the recycler view, 
// it will be attached automatically after the peeking.
val snapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
val peekingHelper = RecyclerViewPeekHelper(yourRecyclerView, snapHelper, peekingDistance, timeBeforeNextPeeking) {
  peekHelper.peek() // Move this lambda somewhere to avoid a reference issue.
}

// After you've added the adapter, layout manager and items the
// to the RecyclerView, call this. If you call it when the
// recycler cannot peek, a log will be displayed on the console.
peekingHelper.peek()
```

**How it works**

When calling `peek()`, a timer is set to wait for `timeBeforePeeking` millis. Then the `SnapHelper` is removed from the `RecyclerView`, and then the recycler is scrolled the `peekingDistance` you specified to simulate the peeking (which should be more than half the width of the view so the peek ends up snapping to the next position). Then it waits for the duration of the peeking to pass before resetting the `SnapHelper` which will snap to the next position. After that, the listener (the lambda) schedules the peeking again. You can customize the duration of the peeking.

**Code**

```kotlin
package es.sdos.android.project.common.android.widget.recycler

import android.util.Log
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.annotation.Px
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.SnapHelper
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference
import java.util.Timer
import java.util.TimerTask
import kotlin.concurrent.timerTask

/**
 *  This will disable the snapHelper and re-enable it after.
 *
 * @property snapHelper The [SnapHelper] set to the recycler, if any, to be able to restore it after the peeking is over.
 */
class RecyclerViewPeekHelper(
  recyclerView: RecyclerView,
  private val snapHelper: PagerSnapHelper,
  @Px val peekingDistance: Int,
  var startPeekingAfter: Long = DEFAULT_START_PEEKING_AFTER,
  var keepPeekingFor: Long = DEFAULT_KEEP_PEEKING_FOR,
  var onPeekOverListener: OnPeekOverListener? = null
) {

  companion object {

    private const val TAG: String = "RecyclerViewPeekHelper"
    const val DEFAULT_START_PEEKING_AFTER = 1000L
    const val DEFAULT_KEEP_PEEKING_FOR = 1000L
  }

  private val recyclerViewWR: WeakReference<RecyclerView> = WeakReference(recyclerView)
  private var scrollOpenTask: TimerTask? = null
  private var scrollBackTask: TimerTask? = null
  private var state: PeekingState = PeekingState.IDLE

  fun peek() {
    when(state) {
      PeekingState.RUNNING -> logIsAlreadyRunningError()
      PeekingState.IDLE -> recyclerViewWR.get()?.run {
        setUpCancellationByUserInteraction()
        // Schedules the first task to scroll the item "open"
        scheduleFirstTask()
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Cancels the peeking tasks and reattaches the snap helper if there was any. Keep in mind that reattaching the
   * snap helper immediately causes the recycler view to snap to its closest view if the peek had already started and
   * the item was "open".
   */
  fun cancelPeek() {
    scrollOpenTask?.cancel()
    scrollOpenTask = null
    scrollBackTask?.cancel()
    scrollBackTask = null
    onPeekFinished(recyclerViewWR.get(), true)
  }

  /**
   * Adds a gesture listener to detect when the user is scrolling. If so, the peeking is cancelled, because if the
   * user has taken control over the scroll, the user's action must prevail over the peeking.
   */
  private fun RecyclerView.setUpCancellationByUserInteraction() {
    setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
      if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        cancelPeek()
      }

      false
    }
  }

  private fun RecyclerView.disableCancellation() {
    setOnTouchListener(null)
  }

  private fun getOrientation(): Orientation = when {
    recyclerViewWR.get()?.layoutManager?.canScrollHorizontally() == true -> Orientation.HORIZONTAL
    recyclerViewWR.get()?.layoutManager?.canScrollVertically() == true -> Orientation.VERTICAL
    else -> Orientation.NOT_SET
  }

  private fun scheduleFirstTask() {
    createStartPeekingTask().run {
      scrollOpenTask = this
      executeAfter(startPeekingAfter)
    }
  }

  private fun createStartPeekingTask(): TimerTask = timerTask {
    ensureCanPeekAndGetOrientation().takeUnless { it == Orientation.NOT_SET }
      ?.let { orientation ->
        // Calculates how much the recycler view must scroll according to the current orientation
        val horizontalPeekingDistance = peekingDistance.takeIfOrZero { orientation == Orientation.HORIZONTAL }
        val verticalPeekingDistance = peekingDistance.takeIfOrZero { orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL }

        // Disables the snapping behaviour if any and performs the peeking scroll
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(null)
        recyclerViewWR.get()?.run {
          post {
            smoothScrollBy(horizontalPeekingDistance, verticalPeekingDistance)

            // Schedules the second task to scroll the item "closed"
            scheduleSecondTask()
          }
        }
      }
  }

  private fun scheduleSecondTask() {
    createStopPeekingTask().run {
      scrollBackTask = this
      executeAfter(keepPeekingFor)
    }
  }

  private fun createStopPeekingTask(): TimerTask = timerTask {
    // Scrolls back the same distance that was scrolled to perform the peeking
    recyclerViewWR.get()?.run { 
      post { onPeekFinished(this, false) }
    }
  }

  private fun onPeekFinished(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dueToCancellation: Boolean) {
    recyclerView?.reset()
    state = PeekingState.IDLE
    onPeekOverListener?.onPeekFinished(dueToCancellation)
  }

  private fun ensureCanPeekAndGetOrientation(): Orientation = getOrientation().also {
    if (it == Orientation.NOT_SET) {
      logMissingElementError()
    }
  }

  private fun logMissingElementError() {
    (recyclerViewWR.get()?.run {
      when {
        adapter == null -> "Cannot peek because the recycler hasn't got an adapter."
        adapter?.itemCount == 0 -> "Cannot peek because the recycler's adapter hasn't got any items."
        layoutManager == null -> "Cannot peek because the recycler hasn't got a LayoutManager."
        else -> "Cannot peek because the recycler's LayoutManager cannot scroll in any direction."
      }
    } ?: "Cannot peek because the reference to the recycler has been garbage-collected.")
      .let { errorMessage -> logError(errorMessage) }
  }

  private fun logIsAlreadyRunningError() {
    logError("Cannot peek because the peeking is already running.")
  }

  private fun logError(message: String) {
    Log.e(TAG, message)
  }

  private fun RecyclerView.reset() {
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(this)
    disableCancellation()
  }

  private fun TimerTask.executeAfter(startAfterMillis: Long) {
    if (startAfterMillis > 0) {
      Timer().schedule(this, startAfterMillis)
    } else {
      run()
    }
  }

  private fun Int.takeIfOrZero(block: (Int) -> Boolean): Int = takeIf(block) ?: 0

  private enum class Orientation {
    HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL, NOT_SET
  }

  private enum class PeekingState {
    IDLE, RUNNING
  }

  fun interface OnPeekOverListener {
    fun onPeekFinished(dueToCancellation: Boolean)
  }
}
```

If, after calling `peek()`, the user scrolls before the peeking is over, the peeking is cancelled so the list won't scroll back while they are holding their finger over the `RecyclerView`. So the `SnapHelper` will be reattached automatically when cancelling the peeking, so you don't have to use an `OnTouchListener` to control this.